# Failed to invoke updateStatus. Message payload is of type: NullPayload

Tags: twitter, mule

Twitter example muleflow with Mule 3.6 EE, Twitter 3.2.0,

Twitter Access Level : Read, write, and direct messages

Here's what's in the shown console:

ERROR 2015-01-30 12:55:02,786 [[twitterdemo].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.retry.notifiers.ConnectNotifier: Failed to connect/reconnect: Work Descriptor. Root Exception was: 401 response received, but no WWW-Authenticate header was present. Type: class java.lang.IllegalStateException
ERROR 2015-01-30 12:55:02,793 [[twitterdemo].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy:

---

Message               : Error sending HTTP request. Message payload is of type: MuleHttpClient$1

### Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2

Exception stack is:
1. 401 response received, but no WWW-Authenticate header was present (java.lang.IllegalStateException)
  com.ning.http.client.providers.grizzly.GrizzlyAsyncHttpProvider$AsyncHttpClientEventFilter$AuthorizationHandler:1623 (null)
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: 401 response received, but no WWW-Authenticate header was present (java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException)
  org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.SafeFutureImpl$Sync:363 (null)
3. java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 401 response received, but no WWW-Authenticate header was present (java.io.IOException)
  org.mule.module.http.internal.request.grizzly.GrizzlyHttpClient:282 (null)
4. Error sending HTTP request. Message payload is of type: MuleHttpClient$1 (org.mule.api.MessagingException)

### org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester:190 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)

Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 401 response received, but no WWW-Authenticate header was present
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.grizzly.GrizzlyAsyncHttpProvider$AsyncHttpClientEventFilter$AuthorizationHandler.handleStatus(GrizzlyAsyncHttpProvider.java:1623)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.grizzly.GrizzlyAsyncHttpProvider$AsyncHttpClientEventFilter.onHttpHeadersParsed(GrizzlyAsyncHttpProvider.java:1422)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.HttpCodecFilter.decodeHttpPacketFromBytes(HttpCodecFilter.java:664)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)

---

Comment: Hi, could you provide your flow please?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is an issue with WWW-authenticate header header in Mule 3.6.x.

I tried a basic twitter flow and it works on Mule 3.5 but not 3.6.

The reported issues are:

- https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-8282
- https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-8127
- https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-8249